# Simple Genetic Algorithm tutorial for timetabling?

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, timetable

My final year project is about automated timetabling using Genetic Algorithm.

First, I'm not asking about a sample working code.

I just need a tutorial in which I can understand more about GA in timetabling.

I currently understand GA operations (selection,crossover,mutation) based on tutorial I found.

But I have no idea on how to apply it onto the timetable. The GA tutorial I looked at encode data in the form of binary or string. But what about for creating timetable?

I hope somebody can guide me to understand about GA in timetabling in more detail. If you have another tutorial of GA that can help me understand GA better, it is welcomed. :)

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Define your individual/genotype** 
Which parameters does a time table have? Can you store them as a bit string or an array of integers?

**Define your fitness function**
Create rules how to calculate the goodness of a time table.

**Define the type of selection**
How to select individuals for mating? Will the best individual be stored during the whole run? (elitism)

**Define genetic operators**
How can two individuals create an offspring? Do you want to use mutation, crossover or both?

**Define parameters for the algorithm**
Will the population size be fixed and new individuals replace old individuals depending on their fitness value (steady state)? Or do you want to create a new generation each time all individuals are evaluated?

**Implement a SGA and test.**